# How to add rich text box in HTML5 Design and also i want to round the corner's as like other textbox?

Tags: html, asp.net, html5-canvas

```
<tr>
    <td class="auto-style3"  >
        <asp:Label ID="Label17" runat="server" CssClass="txtbox" Text="VarCharMax" ></asp:Label></td>
    <td class="auto-style4">
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("VarCharMax") %>' autocomplete="off" Width="209px"  TextMode="MultiLine" BorderColor="#7A7F81" CssClass="txtbox" >
        </asp:TextBox>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Simply modify your existing class like:**

```
.txtbox { border-radius: 4px; }
```